# Arclength parameterization without antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the arc-length parameterization for the following parametric curve:

$$x(t) = \text{sin}(2t^2)*\frac{15t+4\sqrt{510}}{17}$$

$$y(t) = \text{cos}(2t^2)*\frac{15t+4\sqrt{510}}{17}$$

$$z(t) = (t^2\sqrt{510}+8t)$$

I took the derivatives, which I calculated to be
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{15\text{sin}(2t^2)+(4t\text{cos}(2t^2)(15t + 4\sqrt{510})}{17}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{15\text{cos}(2t^2)-(4t\text{sin}(2t^2)(15t + 4\sqrt{510})}{17}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = 2t\sqrt{510}+8$$

Following the arclength parameterization equation below, I plugged in the corresponding derivatives. With both MATLAB and [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), I was told there was no antiderivative that exists for this integral. Is there really no elementary antiderivative for this integral? If so, is there any way that I could still find an arc-length parameterization for this curve?

$$ s(t) = \int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}$$

Comment: This is crazy messy. Why do you need an arclength parametrization?

Comment: I need the arclength parametrization for a project, and they explicitly want an equation and not just a numerical approximation. I think the equations given were randomly generated, which is why they're so messy.

Comment: It's hopeless. Even if you could evaluate the integral explicitly, you would still need to find the inverse function! In differential geometry, in computing curvature and torsion, one can use the chain rule to avoid an explicit reparametrization; tgat's why I asked.

Comment: Alright. Do you think there's any chance this could be computed by hand?

Comment: To be polite, hell no.